# running first program after hadoop single node setup

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

i set up single node hadoop from http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

The problem is when i tru to run the first word count program , and run the command

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

as in tutorial
i get the following error

```
14/04/17 14:50:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s).
```

also when i previously start nodes , they get started but when i call stop script i get the following

```
14/04/17 14:50:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check jps command and its running or not ( namenode, seconderynamenode, jobtracker,tasktracker, datanode) nodes should be run. That's only will run that command.

If you have get any problem download bellow shell script and run the shell script it will install hadoop-1.2.1 and it will run proper way.

https://github.com/tonyreddy/Apache-Hadoop1.2.1-SingleNode-installation-shellscript

Comment: I dont have java of sun , hecne cant use jps . Also , I would sure run the script but it would be better if we could solve this

Comment: Can you tell which os your using